# Access same instance of db connection in different files in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, express

I have 4 files:

```
1) db.js - mongodb connection
2) socket.js - for all socket events
3) route.js - route for /
4) app.js - main start point for express app
```

I want to share same db instance from `db.js in socket.js and route.js` so that the connection to db is made only once.

I have tried 2 ways for this:

```
1) require db.js in both files, but this creates new connection every time require is called.
2) pass the collections in request object in db.js, but then how would I access the request object in socket.js in 

io.on("connection",function(socket){
 // request ??
})
```

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move to a dependency injection setup rather than explicitly requiring `db.js` in each file, that would allow you to reuse your existing `db` connection:

**main.js**

```
// require and setup db like normal
var db = require('./db.js');
// require route, but now call it as a function and pass your db instance
var route = require('./route.js)(db);
```

**route.js**

```
module.exports = function(db, maybeOtherSharedResources) {
  // existing code from route.js
}
```

Comment: This works well for socket.js file but not for route.js. The previously defined API in route.js becomes 404.

route.js now - 

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(model){

    router.post('/save', function(req, res) {
        var myCollection = model().myCollection;
        if (myCollection) {
            //save
        }
        else {
            //error
        }

    });

Comment: You need to ensure that you are returning your routes/etc. from files you end up exporting as functions.

Comment: Implemented and it is working, now the poblem is when I refresh on client side it gives error in route.js on line var myCollection = model().myCollection , says - Trying to open unclosed connection.